# Remix is compiling the smart contract but not solc command

Tags: ether, remix, compilation

I am able to successfully compile a smart contract in remix IDE. However when I try to do the same with solc npm command, it shows a JSON error when compiling.

Voting.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;
contract Voting{
    mapping(bytes32=>uint8) public votesReceived;

    function totalVotesFor(bytes32 candidate) view public returns (uint8){
        return votesReceived[candidate];
    }

    function voteForCandaidate(bytes32 candidate)public{
        votesReceived[candidate]+=1;
    }

 }
```

compile.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
var solc = require('solc');
var code = fs.readFileSync('Voting.sol').toString();
console.log(code);
console.log(solc.compile(code));
```

REMIX IDE is compiling the code without any errors

Compilation error when running the same code with solc

```
{"errors":[{"component":"general","formattedMessage":"* Line 1, Column 1\n  Syntax error: value, object or array expected.\n* Line 1, Column 2\n  Extra non-whitespace afte
r JSON value.\n","message":"* Line 1, Column 1\n  Syntax error: value, object or array expected.\n* Line 1, Column 2\n  Extra non-whitespace after JSON value.\n","severity
":"error","type":"JSONError"}]}
```

Comment: What do you get when you run `solc --version`? Is it 0.4.25 or better?

Comment: You have installed solc v0.5.0 wich uses a different syntaxis. You can force installation of the previous version with `npm install solc@0.4.25`.

Comment: Here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49709000/compile-solidity-with-solc-js-but-get-empty-result, how solc must be used since v0.5.0. Or you can use one of the lowlevel functions.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your code like this:

```
let source = fs.readFileSync(contractPath, 'UTF-8');
let compilationData = solc.compile(source, 1).contracts[':'+ contractName];
```

Make sure you have installed same version of `solc` as mentioned in your contract pragma.

Comment: this helped me to better my understanding